# Can somebody show me why ListView isn't showing?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

The following project was copied verbatim from an online lesson.  It is supposed to display a ListView but nothing shows up.  I am brand new to Android Studio and this is only my second project in it.  There are 5 files and I will display the contents of each of them below.  I just need another pair of eyes or two to find the problem, because I'm "bug blind".  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

> activity_main.xml
>
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> tools:context=".MainActivity">
>
> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/listView"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>     android:visibility="visible"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>
> MainActivity.java
>
> package com.example.tadhg.uiuxadapterpractical;
>
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.res.TypedArray;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.widget.ListView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>   ListView lv;
>   Context context;
>
>   TypedArray images;
>   String [] titleList;
>   String [] descList;
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>       context = this;
>
>       titleList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Languages);
>       descList = 
>  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LanguageDesc);
>       images = 
>  getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.LanguageImg);
>
>       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> OurAdapter.java
>
> package com.example.tadhg.uiuxadapterpractical;
>
> import android.content.Context; import android.content.res.TypedArray;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import
> android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.BaseAdapter; import
> android.widget.ImageView; import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class OurAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>
> ```
> private String [] titles;
> private String [] desc;
> private TypedArray imageID;
>
> private Context context;
> private static LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
>
> //constructor
> OurAdapter(Context adapterContext, String[] titleList, String[] descList, TypedArray images){
>     titles = titleList;
>     desc = descList;
>     imageID = images;
>     context = adapterContext;
>
>     layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return titles.length;
> }
>
> @Override
> public Object getItem(int i) {
>     return i;
> }
>
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int i) {
>     return i;
> }
>
> private class ViewHolder {
>     TextView tv1, tv2;
>     ImageView img;
> }
>
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
>     ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
>
>     if (view == null) {
>         view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, viewGroup, false);
>         viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
>         viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
>         viewHolder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
>
>         view.setTag(viewHolder);
>     } else {
>         viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
>     }
>
>     viewHolder.tv1.setText(titles[position]);
>     viewHolder.tv2.setText(desc[position]);
>     viewHolder.img.setImageResource(imageID.getResourceId(position, 0));
>
>     return view;
> } }
> ```
>
> List_layout.xml
>
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:srcCompat="@drawable/cplus" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView7"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="32dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>     android:text="TextView"
>     android:textSize="24sp"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView8"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="24dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>     android:text="TextView"
>     android:textSize="18sp"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
>     tools:text="TextView" />
> ```
>
> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>
> strings.xml
>
> UIUXAdapterPractical
>
> ```
> <string-array name="Languages">
>     <item>Java</item>
>     <item>Swift</item>
>     <item>C#</item>
>     <item>SQL</item>
>     <item>Javascript</item>
>     <item>Jquery</item>
>     <item>C++</item>
> </string-array>
>
> <string-array name="LanguageDesc">
>     <item>Desc. of Java</item>
>     <item>Desc. of Swift</item>
>     <item>Desc. of C#</item>
>     <item>Desc. of SQL</item>
>     <item>Desc. of Javascript</item>
>     <item>Desc. of Jquery</item>
>     <item>Desc. of C++</item>
> </string-array>
>
> <array name="LanguageImg">
>     <item>@drawable/java</item>
>     <item>@drawable/swift</item>
>     <item>@drawable/csharp</item>
>     <item>@drawable/sql</item>
>     <item>@drawable/js</item>
>     <item>@drawable/jquery</item>
>     <item>@drawable/cplus</item>
> </array> </resources>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed attaching your adapter to listview...you must set your adapter to your `listview` then only you will see your listview

**change your code with following code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    titleList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Languages);
    descList =
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LanguageDesc);
    images =
            getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.LanguageImg);
    final OurAdapter adapter = new OurAdapter(getApplicationContext(),titleList,descList,images);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

### hope it will solve your problem :)

Comment: OMG, thank you all for your help!  It shows up beautifully!  I can't believe the instructor left those lines out!

Comment: @FallenAngel666 If the answer solved your problem, remember to set it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

In your listview you have:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

instead put

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You're forcing the size to be 0 so you can't see it. Tell me if it works

Comment: it doesnt has to do with layout height and width...user havent attached adapter to listview

Comment: It's inside a ConstraintLayout, so 0dp actually means "match constraints".